# Updating data base record only after waiting for 20 sec so the maximum record can be received

Tags: c++

Updating data base record only after waiting for 20 sec so the maximum record can be received.

When a  student record is added from a tool(A tool which adds new student details to the data base) will send an Event ie RecordChangedEvent and this tool can add many records at same time.

**Note :when  RecordChangedEvent is received i have to make a call to changed.list to get the newly added student record**

Let say first time I added 200 records from  tools and tools send  200 **RecordChangedEvent** but here I don't want to receive 200 events rather I will delay by 20 sec  and ignore which comes during this delay.

After coming back from delay I must  call on **changed.list** which will add all the newly  added records which came when it was in 20 sec delay and add them all in a single go.

My problem is that I am getting 200 RecordChangedEvent and it is delayed by 200*20 sec (which is bad). I want to ignore all the events when it is on delay and when it come back after delay just get the update list from  **changed.list**

Below is my approach (inefficient)

```
RecordChangedEvent(void)
{
    static bool lock = false;
    bool updateNewRecord = false;

    // delaying for 20 sec when first event received so that max record can be received
    if(!lock)  
    {
        lock = true;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
        updateNewRecord = true;  
    }
    if(updateNewRecord)
    {
        // adding after 20 sec delay changed.list will have all the updated received records within 20 seconds                
        AddedRecord(changed.list);       
        lock = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with small example this is the 8th days still no response please help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple threads calling `RecordChangedEvent`.  If you only use one thread, that thread will block for 20 seconds before returning, getting the next event, then calling `RecordChangedEvent` again (where it will wait for 20 seconds again).  So you need at least one more thread to handle events while the first thread is sleeping.

Once you have multiple threads, you can still run into problems.  Your `lock` variable is not thread safe.  There is the remote possibility that two threads can enter the `if` with the lock at the same time.  Also, there is no guarantee that a change to `lock` in one thread will be immediately visible in another.  You should use a standard lock object instead.

Another source of problems is that your use of `changed.list` here is unsynchronized, since you're reading from it (either to copy it to pass to `AddRecord` or within `AddRecord` if you pass it in by reference) while elsewhere in your program another thread can be trying to add a new item to the list.

Comment: Can you please show a small example.i feel it like even creating a thread will cause a problem since we don't have a control on the event received because more than 100 or 1000 can be received at a time.